# Change tooltip language of custom plugin Ckedtior

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have made a custom plugin for ckeditor, now i am trying to change the tooltip language dynamically on selected language. I have tried to put the translated tooltip text in corresponding js file in lang folder of ckeditor but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a toolbar button, add it with [editor.ui.addButton](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui-method-addButton) within plugin's [pluginDefinition.init](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.pluginDefinition-method-init), like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'pluginName', {
    lang: 'lan,gua,ges,sup,por,ted,by,this,plu,gin,com,ma,se,pa,ra,ted',
    icons: 'icons,used,by,this,plugin',
    requires: 'anotherPlugin',
    init: function( editor ) {
        // Register the toolbar button.
        if ( editor.ui.addButton ) {
            editor.ui.addButton( 'ButtonName', {
                label: editor.lang.pluginName.labelName, // Your label
                command: 'yourcommand', // Command name
                directional: true, // Depends on BiDi support, optional
                toolbar: 'list,10' // Wherever you want, in fact
            });             
        }
        ...
     }
 });
```

Now supposing your language is `foo`, then `pluginName/lang/foo.js` should look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang( 'pluginName', 'foo', {
    labelName: 'My label!'
});
```

Remember to add `foo` to the `lang` property inside of the object literal of  your `pluginDefinition`:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'pluginName', {
    lang: 'foo',
    ...
 });
```

Generally speaking, `editor.lang.pluginName.labelName` is available inside of `init`, whatever you want to use it for.